# Usage of "on the other hand"

Tags: word-usage, idioms

I wrote:

> On the other hand, there are full automated methods, which don't involve user interaction. the unsupervised approach is feasible if the goal is to extract from a huge number of Web resources.

I didn't use "*on one hand*" before it, I just want to introduce a comparison with the supervised (semi-automated) methods which involve user interaction and has described in the previous paragraph.

Is my usage correct? especially that I used "*on the other hand, there are ...*", should I say something like "*on the other side, there are ...*" or "*on the other end, there are ...*"?!

Comment: I think It is OK, but I think ***fully automated*** is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

"On the other hand" is a common idiom to introduce a competing or contrasting ideas. While you certainly CAN say, "On one hand ... on the other hand ...", it is not necessary.

PS This reminds me of the review of a book by Peter Schickele that says, "On the one hand, Peter Schickele is very funny. On the other hand, he wears a ring." You may need to read that a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

<s>*"On the other hand"* is used to express a contrast between two separate clauses. On the other hand is sometimes paired with *"On one hand"* like so:</s>

> On one hand, it appears all my students are very intelligent. On the other hand, not one of them does any work.

In your case, usage without "On one hand" is also **correct**, you are still creating a contrast between your previously mentioned statement. Depending on your audience you may want to use one of the other terms you listed based on age and formality. Most generally, your current form works perfectly!